# Excel Power Query Index Cycle/Loop

Tags: excel, powerquery

Within Excel Power Query, How would I be able to Loop an Index Number, for example below

```
Data 1 | 1
Data 2 | 2
Data 3 | 4
Data 5 | 1
Data 6 | 2
Data 7 | 3
Data 8 | 4
Data 9 | 1
Data 10| 2
```

and so on

Comment: Can you add a bit more context, and description of the example? Is that just two columns of data? Also, is that purposeful or a typo -- skipping the first index '3' and `Data 4`?

Comment: Yes it will be New Column, I've seen it in a youtube where he extracts data from a report, and he uses the nth line for each to pull the headers using Power Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the absent `Data 4` and `Index 3` are typos, you can use `Number.Mod`

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 4)+1, type number),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Modulo",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: That's the one **Modulo**, its in **Standard** under **Transform**, I remember now, have to highlight the index and click that to get it, thank you so much, much appreciated it